# Backbone.js - place views in separate js file

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to place the views of my application in a separate js file. My code now looks like this:

```
 var SearchApp = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function() { 
    // Bind all functions that uses 'this' as the current object
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addDocument', 'initVisualSearch');
    this.initVisualSearch();
    this.model.bind("change:results", this.render, this);
    this.collection = this.model.get("hits");
    this.collection.bind("add", this.addDocument, this);
    this.collection.bind("reset", function() { this.collection.each(this.addDocument); }, this);

    var detailshtml = '<div id="results-N"></div>';
    detailshtml += '<div class="detailcategory" id="hits_N"></div>';
    this.$el.html(detailshtml); 
    this.model.bind("change:query", function() { 
    }, this);
},
initVisualSearch: function() { 
    this.visualSearch = VS.init({

    });
},
template: _.template($("#template-N").html()),
render : function() {
    this.$el.children("#results-N").html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

});

However, simply creating a new js file and calling

```
 var search = new SearchApp();
```

will not work. I was wondering, is there any easy solution for placing this view outside my html file? Thank you!

Later edit: here is how I am including the relevant javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src="lib/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="lib/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="lib/visualsearch/build/visualsearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3.v2.min.js?2.9.3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/colorbrewer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<script src="js/searchApps.js"></script>
```

The errors that I receive in the console are:

```
undefined is not a function
cannot read property 'model' of undefined
cannot read property 'visualSearch' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you show how you're including all the relevant javascript? I have a feeling you might not be loading the files properly. Are you receiving any errors within console?

Comment: " I am not using any other libraries except underscore.js." hmmm :)

Comment: Indeed, I should have been more clear. Backbone is the most relevant one, I edited my post now.

Comment: As I have posted in my answer you can use dependency manager. requirejs is quite simple yet powerfull and popular.

Comment: Well it looks like your `initialize` function is getting called so the file is being loaded and `SearchApp` is defined. Your errors are coming from within the `initialize` function itself. I see that you don't actually define a `addDocument` function within the view, that would cause the call to `_.bindAll` to fail. Also, you'll need to pass the model when creating the view since your initialize function is dependant on it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use some sort of script loader to manage dependencies between files. For example [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

search_app.js

```
define(['path_to_backbone'], function(Backbone){
   return Backbone.View.extend(...);
});
```

new.js

```
define(['search_app'], function(SearchApp){
   var search = new SearchApp();
})
```

Comment: Require.js is throwing me the error: Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (sApp){
   var SearchApp = new sApp();
}

Comment: RequireJS is completely unnecessary in the context of this question. The issue stems from errors in the `SearchApp` view code and not as the result of dependancy management.

Comment: @BartJedrocha Reread the original question. It clearly states "I would like to place the views of my application in a separate js file." The only reliable way to do it is to use some sort of dependency management. Requirejs is just an example.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Incorrect. Having js in multiple files does not necessitate the use of additional libraries like RequireJS.

Comment: @BartJedrocha Manually maintaining loading order is just another way to hell.

Answer (score -2):

Your load order is correct and from the error messages that you provided, the `initialize` function is being called which means that `SearchApp` is being loaded correctly and instantiated via your call to `new SearchApp()`. I suspect the error is actually within your code.

In your call to `_.bindAll` in the `initialize` function, you pass an 'addDocument` function as a parameter however I don't see it defined within your view. This is most likely the cause of your error as an exception there would prevent the rest of the code from working properly. Please check your code.

Also, when instantiating your view, you'll need to pass the model in the options object since your `initialize` function is dependant on it - example

```
var searchModel = new SearchModel(...)
var searchView = new SearchApp({ model: searchModel})
```

Comment: -1 This answer fix minor issue with code but not address the main one on how to use views from separate files.